# Is it correct to derive the fluid viscosity from momentum conservation law?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, momentum, conservation-laws, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, viscosity

Some books assumes molecules flowing in the x direction for a stationary newtonian fluid, it is defined a microscopic control volume and they says in the top cover (of the box) at level $y_0$  molecules of mass m have more momentum $m v_{x+}$ than molecules below $m v_{x-}$, I agree but they also refers to momentum conservation

$F = \begin{equation}
\oint_S \rho \textbf{v} (\textbf{v}  \cdot \textbf{n} ) dA
\end{equation}$

as the starting point in the derivation of the viscosity expresion. If we are just considering the x direction, so F is indeed $F_x$ and so **v** is $v_x$ and the normal versor **n** in the integral is in the y direction, so the integral must be zero. What's happened?

Comment: The area is oriented perpendicular to the x direction, so the normal to the area is in the x direction.  They are talking about the normal to the area, not the normal to the x direction.

Comment: The $dA$ must become the area of the plate in the Newton's experiment on viscosity. But, the momentum flux in the area normal to x direction must be zero (for developed fluid). Thinking a bit more, the integrand is $\rho*v_x*v_y * dA$, which makes the integral be not zero at first sight

Comment: Ah, yes.  That, of course, makes sense.